# PHP create multi dimensional array

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am querying my database with a LEFT JOIN to get the following array:

```
Array
(
    [invoice_number] => 000010
    [invoice_date] => 1432764000
    [country] => 115
    [fao] => Rick
    [company_name] => Chubbs
    [address_line_1] => kjhk
    [address_line_2] => jh
    [town] => kjh
    [postcode] => kjh
    [filename] => INV-1432820860.pdf
    [id] => 11
    [description] => dfgh
    [rates] => 2
    [quantity] => 3
    [price] => 6
    [created] => 0
    [country_name] => Kazakhstan
)
Array
(
    [invoice_number] => 000010
    [invoice_date] => 1432764000
    [country] => 115
    [fao] => Rick
    [company_name] => Chubbs
    [address_line_1] => kjhk
    [address_line_2] => jh
    [town] => kjh
    [postcode] => kjh
    [filename] => INV-1432820860.pdf
    [id] => 18
    [description] => biscuits
    [rates] => 2
    [quantity] => 3
    [price] => 6
    [created] => 0
    [country_name] => Kazakhstan
)
```

I want to loop through this and remove duplicates, so something like this:

```
Array
    (
        ['inv_details'] => array(
            [invoice_number] => 000010
            [invoice_date] => 1432764000
            [country] => 115
            [fao] => Rick
            [company_name] => Chubbs
            [address_line_1] => kjhk
            [address_line_2] => jh
            [town] => kjh
            [postcode] => kjh
            [filename] => INV-1432820860.pdf
        )
        ['items'] => array(
            [0] => array(
                [description] => dfgh
                [rates] => 2
                [quantity] => 3
                [price] => 6
                [created] => 0
            )
            [1] => array(
                [description] => biscuits
                [rates] => 2
                [quantity] => 3
                [price] => 6
                [created] => 0
            )

        )
    )
```

I have this code at the moment but the items array is not adding two arrays the last item ovewrites the first one and I dont end up with 2 arrays in items, just one:

```
$i = 0;

foreach($res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){

    $form = array();

    $form['title'] = $row['invoice_number'];
    $form['inv_details']['invoice_date'] = array('value'=>gmdate('d/m/Y', $row['invoice_date']), 'type'=>'date');
    $form['inv_details']['company_name'] = array('value' => $row['company_name'], 'type' => 'text');
    $form['inv_details']['fao'] = array('value' => $row['fao'], 'type' => 'text');
    $form['inv_details']['address_line_1'] = array('value' => $row['address_line_1'], 'type' => 'text');
    $form['inv_details']['address_line_2'] = array('value' => $row['address_line_2'], 'type' => 'text');
    $form['inv_details']['town'] = array('value' => $row['town'], 'type' => 'text');
    $form['inv_details']['postcode'] = array('value' => $row['postcode'], 'type' => 'text');
    //$form['inv_details']['countries'] = $this->crm_account_address->getCountries();
    $form['country'] = $row['country_name'];
    $form['country_id'] = $row['id'];

    $form['items'][$i]['description'] = $row['description'];
    $form['items'][$i]['rates'] = $row['rates'];
    $form['items'][$i]['quantity'] = $row['quantity'];
    $form['items'][$i]['price'] = $row['price'];

    //counter
    $i++;

}
```

Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: *I am querying my database ...  and remove duplicates* fix your query statement, take a look at group by

Comment: just move  `$form = array();` above the for loop not inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the array `$form` is initialized every time when iteration occurs. So the previous data is re writes with blank array.

So keep the array initialization in  above you for loop so that it will initialize at first like this

```
$i = 0;

$form = array();    

foreach($res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){

    $form['title'] = $row['invoice_number'];
    $form['inv_details']['invoice_date'] = array('value'=>gmdate('d/m/Y', $row['invoice_date']), 'type'=>'date');
    $form['inv_details']['company_name'] = array('value' => $row['company_name'], 'type' => 'text');
    $form['inv_details']['fao'] = array('value' => $row['fao'], 'type' => 'text');
    $form['inv_details']['address_line_1'] = array('value' => $row['address_line_1'], 'type' => 'text');
    $form['inv_details']['address_line_2'] = array('value' => $row['address_line_2'], 'type' => 'text');
    $form['inv_details']['town'] = array('value' => $row['town'], 'type' => 'text');
    $form['inv_details']['postcode'] = array('value' => $row['postcode'], 'type' => 'text');
    //$form['inv_details']['countries'] = $this->crm_account_address->getCountries();
    $form['country'] = $row['country_name'];
    $form['country_id'] = $row['id'];

    $form['items'][$i]['description'] = $row['description'];
    $form['items'][$i]['rates'] = $row['rates'];
    $form['items'][$i]['quantity'] = $row['quantity'];
    $form['items'][$i]['price'] = $row['price'];

    //counter
    $i++;

}
```

This will work

Comment: Cant believe I put the $form array in the loop! Silly mistake! Thanks for the help!